# WordPress database returning no results after migration

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm having a strange issue, i exported my wordpress database with mysqldump and imported it on command line with mysql client, something i have done countless times, but this time it's behaving in a way i've never come across.

The database connects ok, i get to the wp login screen and it denies access as though i forgot my password, so i ran an update on the user via mysql to create a new temporary md5, it still won't login.

Just as a test i added $wpdb to functions.php in the theme to just do a basic select on the users table:

```
$wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM wp_users LIMIT 20");
```

The result is empty! How? There are literally hundreds of users in the table, if i run the same query directly on mysql it works fine, what is going on here?

Comment: it looks that you have a incomplete dump. Check it with pypmyadmin

Comment: @nbk it's all there! Normally if it's not all there wordpress will throw a connection error, this just isn't selecting any results, the pages on the site are also not loading. All of it is in the database i can see it.

Comment: then you will have a lot of debugging to do, but check first if you are connected to the right database

Comment: Are you sure the result is empty and not a error? could be that the table prefix is incorrect.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast yep no errors, just empty results.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress tables are aliased like this in the `$wpdb` Class https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#tables-2

So your usage implies that the prefix of your table is `wp` which it may or may not be.

So you can do one of two possible things.

1. Use the default alias `users`

```
$wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users LIMIT 20");
```

2. Use the `$wpdb->prefix`

```
$wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users LIMIT 20");
```